# Forward Secrecy not supported with referenced browsers?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, forward-secrecy

I am running a scan against one of our servers from the Qualys SSL tester site and it says that my server "does not support forward secrecy with the referenced browsers". What exactly does that mean? My server is setup to use ECDHE_RSA_* ciphers which I know do support forward secrecy if negotiated and is recognized on the Qualys scan. Is this a browser issue since it says "referenced browsers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The «reference browsers» are marked with an R in the table below. What results were you given there? The problem may be on some of them (IE?) not supporting those ECDHE_RSA_* ciphers.

Comment: Ok yes that's what I thought I just didn't know how to look. I'm on IE 10 which is among the browsers with "R". Thanks!